# Fail to expand a collapsed row with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have an issue and IDK how to made it working.
I have a DataTable with its rows, cols, and stuff.
But I want to make a collapsed row which expands when I click on his "parent" row. I did  this, and works:

```
<tr class="odd gradeX accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#extendDataContainer-<?php echo $row['id_proceso']?>">
 <td>...</td>
 <td>...</td>
 <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr id="extendDataContainer-<?php echo $row['id_proceso']?>" class="collapse accordian-body text-center">
   <td colspan=11>TESTING</td>
</tr>
```

But if you [look][1], DataTables [stopped working][2].
Gives me this
[Error][3]

Any idea how to do a collapsed row and let DataTables still working?
I have this on my .js script for order by first column descending:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
     "order":[[0,"desc"]]
  });
 });
```

[image: how it looks like]

[image: stopped working]

[image: error]

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: "*I did this, and works*" Sorry, but there is no code indicating that this should ever work. Where do you expand the rows? The error you receive is because you are trying to include a row with colspans, which will never work.

Comment: @davidkonrad it works, but DataTables (order, filter, etc) stop working. I want to retrieve data from a DB and expand extra info when I click on the row.